# Difference between SimpleITK.Euler3DTransform and scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler?

Tags: python, scipy, euler-angles, rotational-matrices, simpleitk

Using these two library functions:

- [SimpleITK.Euler3DTransform](https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1Euler3DTransform.html#a87e40500b38c47a46d5ff3b27b3bd341)
- [scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler.html)

to create a simple rotation matrix from Euler Angles:

```
import numpy as np
import SimpleITK as sitk
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
from math import pi

euler_angles = [pi / 10, pi / 18, pi / 36]

sitk_matrix = sitk.Euler3DTransform((0, 0, 0), *euler_angles).GetMatrix()
sitk_matrix = np.array(sitk_matrix).reshape((3,3))
print(np.array_str(sitk_matrix, precision=3, suppress_small=True))

order = 'XYZ' # Different results for any order in ['XYZ','XZY','YZX','YXZ','ZXY','ZYX','xyz','xzy','yzx','yxz','zxy','zyx']
scipy_matrix = Rotation.from_euler(order, euler_angles).as_matrix()
print(np.array_str(scipy_matrix, precision=3, suppress_small=True))
```

I get two different results:

```
[[ 0.976 -0.083  0.2  ]
 [ 0.139  0.947 -0.288]
 [-0.165  0.309  0.937]]
[[ 0.981 -0.086  0.174]
 [ 0.136  0.943 -0.304]
 [-0.138  0.322  0.937]]
```

Why? How can I compute the same matrix as SimpleITK using scipy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `itk.Euler3DTransform` class by default applies the rotation matrix multiplications in `Z @ X @ Y` order and the `Rotation.from_euler` function in `Z @ Y @ X` order.

Note that this is independent of the `order` you specified. The order you specify refers to the order of the angles, not the order of the matrix multiplications.

If you are using the `itk.Euler3DTransform` directly as you showed in your example, you can actually change the default behavior for itk to perform the matrix multiplication in `Z @ Y @ X` order.

I never worked with sitk but in theory and [based on the documentation](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1Euler3DTransform.html#a55ee51b3ed16fc92d0cee6d2113a0a1d), something like this should work:

```py
euler_transform = sitk.Euler3DTransform((0, 0, 0), *euler_angles)
euler_transform.SetComputeZYX(True)
sitk_matrix = euler_transform.GetMatrix()
```

Alternatively, I wrote a function which is similar to `Rotation.from_euler` but has the option to specify the rotation order as well:

```py
from typing import List
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def build_rotation_3d(radians: NDArray,
                      radians_oder: str = 'XYZ',
                      rotation_order: str = 'ZYX',
                      dims: List[str] = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']) -> NDArray:
    x_rad, y_rad, z_rad = radians[(np.searchsorted(dims, list(radians_oder)))]
    x_cos, y_cos, z_cos = np.cos([x_rad, y_rad, z_rad], dtype=np.float64)
    x_sin, y_sin, z_sin = np.sin([x_rad, y_rad, z_rad], dtype=np.float64)
    x_rot = np.asarray([
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, x_cos, -x_sin, 0.0],
        [0.0, x_sin, x_cos, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ])
    y_rot = np.asarray([
        [y_cos, 0.0, y_sin, 0.0],
        [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [-y_sin, 0.0, y_cos, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ])
    z_rot = np.asarray([
        [z_cos, -z_sin, 0.0, 0.0],
        [z_sin, z_cos, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ])

    rotations = np.asarray([x_rot, y_rot, z_rot])[(np.searchsorted(dims, list(rotation_order)))]

    return rotations[0] @ rotations[1] @ rotations[2]
```

To get the respective rotation matrix which matches the EulerTransform:

```py
rotation_matrix = build_rotation_3d(numpy.array(euler_angles),
                                    radians_oder = 'XYZ',
                                    rotation_order = 'ZXY')
```

Comment: (`Rotation.from_euler` additionally has uppercase and lowercase "orders" to switch between extrinsic and intrinsic angles.) So `Rotation.from_euler` can not be used to get the same result as `sitk.Euler3DTransform`? What is the call for `build_rotation_3d` that gives the same result as `sitk.Euler3DTransform`?

Comment: @Peter Added an example for the usage of `build_rotation_3d`.

Comment: Code has some issues: NDArray and List are not defined. (`from numpy import ndarray as NDArray`? `from typing import List`) SyntaxError (Remove `: str` in usage example) `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` (no idea)

Comment: For NDArray: `from numpy.typing import NDArray`. Good catch on the example, I just wrote it here without executing it. The last one might be due to directly passing a list as euler_angles? Convert it to a numpy array first: `np.asarray(euler_angles, dtype=np.float64)`.
I will improve the code example soon.

Comment: Seems to work now. (4x4 instead of 3x3 matrix, but not a problem.)

Comment: That is because it returns a homogeneous affine matrix. The 4x4 can also include translations and can be used to compute a chain of affine transformations. It is a very useful notation.

Answer (score 0):

What is your 'order' string.  When I ran your code with order='xyz', I get the same results for SimpleITK and scipy's Rotation.

Comment: See edited question. I tried `order` in `['XYZ','XZY','YZX','YXZ','ZXY','ZYX','xyz','xzy','yzx','yxz','zxy','zyx']`, none seems to give the same answer as SimpleITK this example.